# The product of two nonzero numbers is equal to twice the sum. Find their sum of their reciprocals.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$xy = 2x+2y$

$\frac{xy}{2} = x+y$

A hint was given as "What must we divide the sum of $x$ and $y$ by to get the sum of the reciprocals of $x$ and $y$"

$\frac{x+y}{a}= \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$

$\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{a}= \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$

The hint hasn't been helpful for me and I can't see how to move forward.

Comment: Can you solve that equation for $a$?

Comment: Take $xy=2x+2y$, divide by $xy$ and you get $$1=\frac{2x+2y}{xy}=\frac{2x}{xy}+\frac{2y}{xy}=\frac{2}{y}+\frac{2}{x}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of the reciprocals is $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}$. Finding the common denominator, we can calculate this to $\frac{x + y}{xy}$. We know that $xy = 2(x + y)$. So, $\frac{x + y}{xy} = \frac{x + y}{2(x + y)} = \boxed{\frac{1}{2}}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint

$$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = \frac{\text{(what?)}}{xy}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $xy=2x+2y=2(x+y)$, you have$$\frac{x+y}{xy}=\frac12,$$which is equivalent to$$\frac1y+\frac1x=\frac12.$$

Comment: I think you meant $\frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{x}$, no $\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x}$

Comment: @jjagmath Sure. I've edited my answer. Thank you.